# Override field with parameterless method

Tags: scala, oop

I am currently learning Scala and I am reading (from cover to cover) Martin Ordesky's book. In chapter 10 I found this:

[image]

Great I both understand and like this. So I tried an example:

```
class Father {
    def x = 1 // Method
}

class Child extends Father {
    override val x = 1; // Field
}
```

However, if you try to override an attribute with a method:

```
class Father {
    val x = 1; // Field
}

class Child extends Father  {
    override def x = 1 // Method
}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
method x needs to be a stable, immutable value
   override def x = 1
```

It doesn't work neither if `x` in `Father` is `var`:

```
method x cannot override a mutable variable
  override def x = 1
```

So we have two cases (and my two questions):

- **Trying to override an inmutable field:** Is this forbidden in order to guarantee `x` won't be overriden by a method whose value changes over time? Is there any other reason?
- **Trying to override a mutable field:** Why can't a mutable field be overriden? I initially thought that it is to avoid class users assigning values to parameterless methods but then no parameterless method should be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing overriding of a `val` by a `def` would require going through lots of hoops in the generated constructor, and there would be redundant fields in subclasses. It's technically possible to implement this but there are no benefits.

Allowing overriding of a `var` by a `def` wouldn't make sense. What would assigning to it mean?

Comment: What whould assigning anything to a parameterless method mean? However there are parameterless methods and assignment is forbidden .

Comment: You can only assign to `var`, so allowing overridding `var` by something else makes no sense. (Liskov substitution principle.)

Comment: I agree but then why this: `class Someclass { def x = 3 };` This `o = new Someclass` `o.x = 4` is absurd so, following your reasoning, parameterless methods should not be allowed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Parameterless methods should be allowed, but they should not be allowed to override mutable variables, since assigning to methods is indeed absurd, but assigning to mutable variables isn't.

Comment: I understand the language helps you move towards inmutability. Thus you can concrete a class method to an inmutable field but never otherwise.